# Returning values which compute sum

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Here is a Scala stream to calculate the Fibonacci sequence :

```
    import scala.math.BigInt

    object fib extends App {

      val fibs: Stream[BigInt] = BigInt(0) #:: BigInt(1) #:: fibs.zip(
        fibs.tail).map(n => {
          n._1 + n._2
        })
    }
  fibs take 5 foreach println
  fibs take 6 foreach println
```

src : http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream

Instead of taking the first n numbers in the sequence how to sum the first n numbers using a stream , and return this sum ?

I could introduce a var `sum` like this :

```
object fib extends App {

    var sum = 3;
  val fibs: Stream[BigInt] = BigInt(0) #:: BigInt(1) #:: fibs.zip(fibs.tail).map(n => {

      sum = n._1.toInt + n._2.toInt
      n._1 + n._2

    })

  fibs take 5 foreach println

}
```

And then somehow check this summed value. But this is not a good solution.

Update : I'm attempting to provide the summed value and return values that compute this sum, not sum the actual stream.

So `takeSum(7)` will return `'0,1,1,2,3'`

Assumption is that the n value sum will contain a subset of the fib sequence

Comment: My favorite fib stream: `def fib: Stream[BigInt] = 0 #:: fib.scan(1:BigInt)(_+_)`

Comment: what happens if the parameter passed to takeSum has a value that is not the sum of some prefix of the fib stream (e.g. 8)?

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul assumption is that the n value sum will contain a subset of the fib sequence

Comment: So your question is "how to return the prefix of the stream whose sum is a specified value"?

Comment: @The Archetypal Paul yes, thanks for clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want something along the lines of...

```
fibs.takeWhile(f => fibs.takeWhile(_ <= f).sum <= n)
```

...where `n` is the target sum.

Not a terribly efficient implementation but I think it gets the job done.

Or, alternatively.

```
fibs.take( fibs.tail.scan(0:BigInt)(_+_).indexWhere(_>n) )
```

A little more verbose but a little less repetition of effort.

Answer (score 4):

You can just use the `sum`-method on `Stream`. It will work with all types that have an implicit `Numeric[T]` implementation available (such as `Int`, `Long`, `Double`, `BigInt` and so on).

```
fibs.take(5).sum
```

Comment: I'm attempting to provide the summed value and return values that compute this sum, not sum the actual stream. I've updated question, apologies for ambiguity

Answer (score 0):

```
def takeSum(n:Int) = fib.scanLeft(List[BigInt]()){(b,a)=> a::b}
                        .find(_.sum==n)
                        .get
                        .reverse
 takeSum(7)  //> res0: List[BigInt] = List(0, 1, 1, 2, 3)
```

The `scanLeft` builds prefixes of the stream (with the prefix in reverse order), then it's just a matter of finding the one with the right sum. If your assumption is that the n value will be the sum of a subset of the fib sequence is not valid, it will not terminate! You could change it to `>=` if that's important